# SVN - how to view the revision tree?

Tags: svn, version-control

Say that our SVN repository is at revision 400, and I implement a new feature and commit it as r401.

My colleague doesn't like it, reverts back to r400 and implements the feature more efficiently, then commits it as r402.

Is there a tool that will show us both r401 and r402 as nodes on a tree, stemming from r400?

Comment: Can you not just view the log? What exactly are you wanting to see?

Comment: I dont know if you want this _Can create a graph of all revisions/commits. You can then easily see where you created a tag/branch or modified a file/folder_ then go for tortoisesvn if you are on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the [Revision graph](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-revgraph.html)

In the case you described when your colleague revert they dont revert the repository but their working copy, as soon as they commit they will produce another transaction in the log which shows you then the changes from 400 to 401 and then from 401 to 402.

Comment: Like @O.D says, TortoiseSVN has a Revision graph.

Comment: So you can't separate the development "dead-ends" and reverted revisions, unless you make a branch beforehand? The reason I'm asking is that reverting a commit is not an unusual thing in our team, as we try out new approaches and technologies, and all those revisions are cluttering the log and making it hard to see the big picture.

Comment: How would you define a DeadEnd?? as i understand your question the answer is yes you can. You commit change A (r401), i update my working copy, click on show log and choose for instance the option "revert changes from this revision", this causes my woking copy to look exactly like the revision before your changes (but i dont have r400, but r401 with your changes back), and the log still shows you commited a change on the repository. I Make Change B and commit (r402)... once you show the log you will c r400 -> r401 -> r402

Comment: Log shows everthing that's part of the history of the file. Oh and you certainly can branch after the fact (just copy r400 to the new branch, instead of HEAD)

Answer (score 1):

This use case cannot be graphed, because r402 will always be based off r401 (given that no other commits are made to other files ofcourse). To revert r401, your colleague would reverse merge r401, and commit that as r402.

A graph would look like:

```
r400 -> r401 -> r402
```